# How to store multiple results for the same query in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to React-redux.. I am trying to implement some basic functionality of querying the database for a "system type" and store the results in redux store.. The problem I have with my current implementation is that the results of the previous query are getting overwritten by the results from the current query..  The user clicks on "system type x" first and the appropriate profile info is displayed, and when he clicks on "system type y" the result is overwriting the earlier results in redux store.. I dont want to write separate methods or initial states for each "system type", because new "system types" could get added in live.

Could anyone provide guidance on how to implement it.. I have copied my key files below.. Thanks in advance..

**RootReducer**

```
const RootReducer = combineReducers({
   getSystemProfile: GetSystemProfileReducer
})
```

**GetSystemProfileReducer**

```
 const initialState = {
    Error: null,
    SystemProfile: []
}

const GetSystemProfileReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'GET_DATA':
            const newstate = {...state, Error:'', SystemProfile: action.data};
            return newstate

        case 'GET_DATA_ERROR':
            console.log("Fetch system data failed")
            return {...state, Error: 'Fetch Failed'}

        default:
           return state  
    }
}
```

**GetSystemProfileAction**

```
export const getSystemProfile  = (systemtype) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        fetch('https://xxx/profile/'+systemtype, {
            method: 'get',
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            dispatch({type : "GET_DATA", data})
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            dispatch({type:'GET_DATA_ERROR', err})
        });
    }
}
```

**SystemView.js**

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      systemProfile: state.getSystemProfile.SystemProfile
    }
  }

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
            getSystemProfile: (systemtype) => dispatch(getSystemProfile(systemtype)),
        }
}
```

Comment: why dont you push your new result to the existing state, like `SystemProfile: [...state.SystemProfile, action.data]`, I hope you get my point

Answer (score 0):

You should not ignore systemtype on your reducer,
My suggestion is to replace the array on your reducer with map which the key is your type and the value is a list

```
case 'GET_DATA':
   const newstate = {...state, Error:'', state[action.payload.systemtype]: SystemProfile: action.payload.data};
   return newstate
```

And your action should dispatch the data list and systemtype

Second options is to add systemtype for each item in the list and concat the current list with new list.

```
SystemProfile: [...state.SystemProfile, action.data]
```